# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF1\xE0\xEB\xEE\xED\xFB...' for column 'about' at row 1

Tags: mysql

Есть парсер на yii2 ( php ). Он парсит текст с различных сайтов и вставляет в базу.
При попытке сохранить в базу выдаёт такое сообщение об ошибке.

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF1\xE0\xEB\xEE\xED\xFB...' for column 'about' at row 1
```

Версия Mysql 5.7
Кодировки

```
--------------
show variables like '%colla%'
--------------

+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%charac%';
--------------
show variables like '%charac%'
--------------

+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Конфиг подключения к БД

```
'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yiiutf8',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'xxxx',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

Пробовал менять кодировки на

- utf8mb4
- utf8_general_ci
- utf8_unicode_ci
- utf8mb4_general_ci
- utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: у Вас строка в cp1251 (там написано салоны), а Вы ее пытаетесь как utf-8 строку декодировать. А для кириллического текста так нельзя.

Скорее всего Вам нужно строку обработать чем то таким ` $messageutf8 = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $message1251);`

Comment: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\x8D\x0A\xD0...' for column 'about' at row 1 ....
Помогло в первом случае, но не не вставляет Utf8